# How do I fire an event from a button inside a child view to trigger an event on parent View? Button is not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, mobile

I am trying to create a verification process in 4 steps, in order to make my code more efficient, I decided to use Child views and just update the UI accordingly.
I managed to add my child view to my MasterView, however, I am unable to click the button inside my child view.

I already checked the view hierarchy and there is nothing on top of my button. I also tried to add the action programmatically, re-added the button but I can't make it work. I am new to swift development so probably I am missing something.

Child view Code

```
protocol IdentityVerificationIntroChildViewControllerDelegate{
    func startVIProcess(_ sender: Any)
}

class IdentityVerificationIntroChildViewController: UIView{
    
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    var delegate: IdentityVerificationIntroChildViewControllerDelegate?
    @IBOutlet weak var mStartVIBtn: UIButton!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    
    private func commonInit(){
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("IdentityVerificationIntroChildView", owner: self, options: nil)
        mStartVIBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]


    }
    
    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("works")
    }
    
}
```

Master view code

```
final class MasterIdentityVerificationViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mContainerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mStepIndicator: StepIndicatorView!
    
    private var currentView: UIView?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setChildView(subView: IdentityVerificationIntroChildViewController())
    }
    
    private func setChildView(subView: UIView){
        currentView?.removeFromSuperview()
        currentView = subView
        currentView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        guard let currentView = currentView else { return }
        mContainerView.addSubview(currentView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            currentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mContainerView.topAnchor),
            currentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mContainerView.trailingAnchor),
            currentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mContainerView.leadingAnchor),
            currentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mContainerView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
}


extension MasterIdentityVerificationViewController: IdentityVerificationIntroChildViewControllerDelegate{
    func startVIProcess(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromVIIntroToVIIDCapture", sender: sender)
        print("adfsdfs")
    }
    

}
```

[View Hierarchy, the problematic button is Highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4CXb.jpg)

[Green Area is where Child views are getting switched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9zqm.png)

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: It is slightly misleading to have "viewcontroller" in the name of a view.  Regardless, you need to set `userInteractionEnabled=true` on your child views

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your answer, I tried with no luck these lines inside my child view
        mStartVIBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: You need `self.isUserInteractionEnabled=true` since `self` is your parent view and plain `UIView`s don't have user interaction by default.